# Empathy does not allow WLM accounts after upgrade to ubuntu 12.04

Tags: empathy

AFter upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04, all my accounts previously configured in Empathy were deleted. Then, I tried t set them up again, but I see that the WLM accounts are not an option in the account types allowed by Empathy.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this too. I found this helped:

```
sudo aptitude install telepathy-haze
```

Then open the Chat client, and Ctrl-Q to quit it completely, then run it again and try to add the account again, and it works (or it picked up my old accounts anyway).